# A French fantasy movie in a prison cell from which the prisoners try to escape with black magic

Tags: story-identification, movie

This French movie is from the early 2000, maybe 2004 or 2005. Four or five prisoners share the same cell and one of them is into black magic. He tries out different spells. With one of them, they can go through the wall. One of them tries it with his hand, but the wall solidifies again and he loses his right hand fingers.

"The wall has eaten my fingers!" was his line. One of the other replied something like "We will escape by pieces."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Never watched it but this seems to be the one: [Maléfique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mal%C3%A9fique)

> The cellmates discover, hidden behind a loose brick of the cell-wall, an old hand-written journal which belonged to a prisoner named Danvers in the 1920s who mysteriously disappeared from his cell. The book is filled with incantations and symbols of black magic. Although sceptical, Carrere reads aloud one of the incantations and the prisoners are shocked when a bright, burning symbol briefly materialises on the floor. Carrere, and then Lassalle both study the book and they begin to have disturbing visions. Paquerette wakes up one morning to find that during the night, his fingers have vanished.
>
> The cellmates argue over what to do with the book. Paquerette grabs the book and starts to eat its pages only to be over-powered by an unseen force which twists his entire body until his spine and neck snap. The other three prisoners are blamed by the guards for Paquerette's death, condemning them to stay in prison for life. Lasselle believes that the book was defending itself. A new prisoner named Picus arrives, a friendly, eccentric man who always carries a video camera. Later, the others wake up one morning to find that Picus has disappeared, leaving his camera and the journal on the floor. They watch the last piece of footage on the camera in which Picus reads an incantation from the book whereupon a brightly lit doorway appears on the wall through which he walks. They ask the guards about Picus but the latter reply that they do not know who the cellmates are talking about, revealing that Picus was a hallucination concocted by the book, designed to reveal the book's true powers.

Comment: Nice find! How did you find it?

Comment: Whilst Fuzzy has included some basic information on the film could you also [edit] this to explain how it matches the OP's description?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I just searched the google results with keywords like "prison break", "movie", "french", "black magic" and so on

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's the movie I was searching for :)